# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime when parse exact

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm getting this error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

When trying to parse this date:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("2015-08-05", "YYYY-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

What's wrong with the date format and how do I fix this?

Comment: `"YYYY-MM-dd"` is unknown format specifier, try with `"yyyy-MM-dd"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "YYYY" portion needs to be lower-case:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("2015-08-05", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

*Reference: [The "yyyy" Custom Format Specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#yyyySpecifier)*